# Discrepance between simulator and physical device on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, constraints

I'm developing an app using Xamarin for iOS.
I have a case where the simulator and a physical device is not displaying a view created with storyboard the same way.
In this case, there are two UIButtons that are placed horizontally. The first one has four constraints:

- Top Space to: View Controller Layout Guide
- Leading Space to: Superview
- Trailing Space to: "SecondButton"
- Height Equal: 42

The second one has also four constraints:

- Top Space to: View Controller Layout Guide
- Trailing Space to: Superveiw
- Trailing Space to(This is the first button): Button Control(This is the second button)
- Height Equal: 42

This should produce two buttons of equal width that each are half the width of the Superview. And this is how it is displayed in the simulator and on iPhone 5s physical devices. However on iPhone 6 the second button occupies most of the width and the first button is barely visible on the left side. (See screenshots).

Device:[image: What it looks like on the physical device]

Simulator:[image: What it should look like on device and how it looks on simulator and iPhone5]

Can anyone offer some advice on why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to set to one of buttons, that width equals to width of the other one.

Also check this:

> Trailing Space to: Superveiw
>
> Trailing Space to(This is the first button): Button Control(This is the second button)

Maybe I do not understand, but this looks strange. Havent you mean Leading Space on second line?

Comment: Trailing Space to(This is the first button): Button Control(This is the second button) this is basically the same as "Trailing Space to: "SecondButton"" only in reverse. (They share the constraint)

Comment: Thank you. But you are still not giving your buttons any information about their supposed width - except, that together it shall be the width of Superview. Both device and simulator are fulfilling all of your constraint. Set width of both buttons to be the same and this shall fix your problem.